# Basic Approach To Independence In Probability

Tags: probability

If we have an event $A$ and a sample space $\Omega$, can we say that the event $A$ is Independent on an event $B$ if the occurrence of $B$ keep the ratio of $\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}$?

For example: looking at a deck of cards, P(heart)=$\frac{13}{52}$ and P(king)=$\frac{4}{52}$ assume we show the card is red.

now P(heart|red)=$\frac{13}{52-26}=\frac{13}{26}\neq$ P(heart)=$\frac{13}{52}$

but P(king|red)=$\frac{4-2}{52-26}=\frac{2}{26}=$P(king)=$\frac{4}{52}=\frac{2}{26}$

Comment: I think you have it right, but the phrasing is a little unclear.  The usual definition is that P(A|B) = P(A), i.e. "the probability that A has occurred is unchanged if we are told that B has occurred".

Comment: @lulu Independence is defined as $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ and not in terms of conditional probability.  The two definitions are not equivalent because conditional probability is undefined when the conditioning event has probability zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by Definition you have for the conditional probability that, given $P(B)>0$, $P(A|B) = \frac {P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} $. Therefore if A and B are Independent, we have $P(A \cap B) = P(A) * P(B)$. Then $P(A|B) = P(A)$, so indeed the probability remains unchanged.